# API for On-Demand trigger for the Azure Data Sync

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

Is there anyway we can trigger the Azure Data Sync on-demand via API without using the automatically sync?

Comment: Azure Data sync document said that Data Sync tracks changes using insert, update, and delete triggers. The changes are recorded in a side table in the user database. Note that BULK INSERT does not fire triggers by default. If FIRE_TRIGGERS is not specified, no insert triggers execute. Add the FIRE_TRIGGERS option so Data Sync can track those inserts.It maybe can helps you trigger the Azure Data Sync on-demand. But I still haven't find some tutorials or blogs talked about how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about any open API but here is the powershell script to trigger azure data sync manually. It includes the HUB, Manual and sync DB creation and adding a trigger manully.

You can use this to create custom api and trigger it from your code.

```
# prerequisites: 
# 1. Create an Azure SQL Database from AdventureWorksLT sample database as hub database
# 2. Create an Azure SQL Database in the same region as sync database
# 3. Create an Azure SQL Database as member database
# 4. Update the parameters below before running the sample
#
using namespace Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.DataSync.Model
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

# Hub database info
# Subscription id for hub database
$SubscriptionId = "subscription_guid"
# Resource group name for hub database
$ResourceGroupName = "ResourceGroup"
# Server name for hub database
$ServerName = "Server"
# Database name for hub database
$DatabaseName = "AdventureWorks"

# Sync database info
# Resource group name for sync database
$SyncDatabaseResourceGroupName = "ResourceGroup"
# Server name for sync database
$SyncDatabaseServerName = "Server"
# Sync database name
$SyncDatabaseName = "SyncDatabase"

# Sync group info
# Sync group name
$SyncGroupName = "SampleSyncGroup1"
# Conflict resolution Policy. Value can be HubWin or MemberWin
$ConflictResolutionPolicy = "HubWin"
# Sync interval in seconds. Value must be no less than 300
$IntervalInSeconds = 300

# Member database info
# Member name
$SyncMemberName = "member"
# Member server name
$MemberServerName = "MemberServer"
# Member database name
$MemberDatabaseName = "SyncDatabase1"
# Member database type. Value can be AzureSqlDatabase or SqlServerDatabase
$MemberDatabaseType = "AzureSqlDatabase"
# Sync direction. Value can be Bidirectional, Onewaymembertohub, Onewayhubtomember
$SyncDirection = "Bidirectional"

# Other info
# Temp file to save the sync schema
$TempFile = $env:TEMP+"\syncSchema.json"

# List of included columns and tables in quoted name
$IncludedColumnsAndTables =  "[SalesLT].[Address].[AddressID]",
                             "[SalesLT].[Address].[AddressLine2]",
                             "[SalesLT].[Address].[rowguid]",
                             "[SalesLT].[Address].[PostalCode]",
                             "[SalesLT].[ProductDescription]"
$MetadataList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new($IncludedColumnsAndTables)


Connect-AzAccount 
select-Azsubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId

# Use this section if it is safe to show password in the script.
# Otherwise, use the PromptForCredential
# $User = "username"
# $PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Password" -AsPlainText -Force
# $Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $User, $PWord

$Credential = $Host.ui.PromptForCredential("Need credential", 
              "Please enter your user name and password for server "+$ServerName+".database.windows.net", 
              "", 
              "")

# Create a new sync group
Write-Host "Creating Sync Group"$SyncGroupName
New-AzSqlSyncGroup   -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                            -ServerName $ServerName `
                            -DatabaseName $DatabaseName `
                            -Name $SyncGroupName `
                            -SyncDatabaseName $SyncDatabaseName `
                            -SyncDatabaseServerName $SyncDatabaseServerName `
                            -SyncDatabaseResourceGroupName $SyncDatabaseResourceGroupName `
                            -ConflictResolutionPolicy $ConflictResolutionPolicy `
                            -DatabaseCredential $Credential

# Use this section if it is safe to show password in the script.
#$User = "username"
#$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
#$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $User, $Password

$Credential = $Host.ui.PromptForCredential("Need credential", 
              "Please enter your user name and password for server "+$MemberServerName, 
              "", 
              "")

# Add a new sync member
# You can add members from other subscriptions, you don't need to specify Subscription Id for the member
Write-Host "Adding member"$SyncMemberName" to the sync group"
New-AzSqlSyncMember   -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                            -ServerName $ServerName `
                            -DatabaseName $DatabaseName `
                            -SyncGroupName $SyncGroupName `
                            -Name $SyncMemberName `
                            -MemberDatabaseCredential $Credential `
                            -MemberDatabaseName $MemberDatabaseName `
                            -MemberServerName ($MemberServerName + ".database.windows.net") `
                            -MemberDatabaseType $MemberDatabaseType `
                            -SyncDirection $SyncDirection

# Refresh database schema from hub database
# Specify the -SyncMemberName parameter if you want to refresh schema from the member database
Write-Host "Refreshing database schema from hub database"
$StartTime= Get-Date
Update-AzSqlSyncSchema   -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                              -ServerName $ServerName `
                              -DatabaseName $DatabaseName `
                              -SyncGroupName $SyncGroupName


#Waiting for successful refresh

$StartTime=$StartTime.ToUniversalTime()
$timer=0
$timeout=90
# Check the log and see if refresh has gone through
Write-Host "Check for successful refresh"
$IsSucceeded = $false
While ($IsSucceeded -eq $false)
{
    Start-Sleep -s 10
    $timer=$timer+10
    $Details = Get-AzSqlSyncSchema -SyncGroupName $SyncGroupName -ServerName $ServerName -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
    if ($Details.LastUpdateTime -gt $StartTime)
      {
        Write-Host "Refresh was successful"
        $IsSucceeded = $true
      }
    if ($timer -eq $timeout) 
      {
              Write-Host "Refresh timed out"
        break;
      }
}



# Get the database schema 
Write-Host "Adding tables and columns to the sync schema"
$databaseSchema = Get-AzSqlSyncSchema   -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                             -ServerName $ServerName `
                                             -DatabaseName $DatabaseName `
                                             -SyncGroupName $SyncGroupName `

$databaseSchema | ConvertTo-Json -depth 5 -Compress | Out-File "c:\tmp\databaseSchema"     
$newSchema = [AzureSqlSyncGroupSchemaModel]::new()
$newSchema.Tables = [List[AzureSqlSyncGroupSchemaTableModel]]::new();

# Add columns and tables to the sync schema
foreach ($tableSchema in $databaseSchema.Tables)
{
    $newTableSchema = [AzureSqlSyncGroupSchemaTableModel]::new()
    $newTableSchema.QuotedName = $tableSchema.QuotedName
    $newTableSchema.Columns = [List[AzureSqlSyncGroupSchemaColumnModel]]::new();
    $addAllColumns = $false
    if ($MetadataList.Contains($tableSchema.QuotedName))
    {
        if ($tableSchema.HasError)
        {
            $fullTableName = $tableSchema.QuotedName
            Write-Host "Can't add table $fullTableName to the sync schema" -foregroundcolor "Red"
            Write-Host $tableSchema.ErrorId -foregroundcolor "Red"
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            $addAllColumns = $true
        }
    }
    foreach($columnSchema in $tableSchema.Columns)
    {
        $fullColumnName = $tableSchema.QuotedName + "." + $columnSchema.QuotedName
        if ($addAllColumns -or $MetadataList.Contains($fullColumnName))
        {
            if ((-not $addAllColumns) -and $tableSchema.HasError)
            {
                Write-Host "Can't add column $fullColumnName to the sync schema" -foregroundcolor "Red"
                Write-Host $tableSchema.ErrorId -foregroundcolor "Red"c            }
            elseif ((-not $addAllColumns) -and $columnSchema.HasError)
            {
                Write-Host "Can't add column $fullColumnName to the sync schema" -foregroundcolor "Red"
                Write-Host $columnSchema.ErrorId -foregroundcolor "Red"
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "Adding"$fullColumnName" to the sync schema"
                $newColumnSchema = [AzureSqlSyncGroupSchemaColumnModel]::new()
                $newColumnSchema.QuotedName = $columnSchema.QuotedName
                $newColumnSchema.DataSize = $columnSchema.DataSize
                $newColumnSchema.DataType = $columnSchema.DataType
                $newTableSchema.Columns.Add($newColumnSchema)
            }
        }
    }
    if ($newTableSchema.Columns.Count -gt 0)
    {
        $newSchema.Tables.Add($newTableSchema)
    }
}

# Convert sync schema to Json format
$schemaString = $newSchema | ConvertTo-Json -depth 5 -Compress

# workaround a powershell bug
$schemaString = $schemaString.Replace('"Tables"', '"tables"').Replace('"Columns"', '"columns"').Replace('"QuotedName"', '"quotedName"').Replace('"MasterSyncMemberName"','"masterSyncMemberName"')

# Save the sync schema to a temp file
$schemaString | Out-File $TempFile

# Update sync schema
Write-Host "Updating the sync schema"
Update-AzSqlSyncGroup  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                            -ServerName $ServerName `
                            -DatabaseName $DatabaseName `
                            -Name $SyncGroupName `
                            -Schema $TempFile

$SyncLogStartTime = Get-Date

# Trigger sync manually
Write-Host "Trigger sync manually"
Start-AzSqlSyncGroupSync  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                               -ServerName $ServerName `
                               -DatabaseName $DatabaseName `
                               -SyncGroupName $SyncGroupName

# Check the sync log and wait until the first sync succeeded
Write-Host "Check the sync log"
$IsSucceeded = $false
For ($i = 0; ($i -lt 300) -and (-not $IsSucceeded); $i = $i + 10)
{
    Start-Sleep -s 10
    $SyncLogEndTime = Get-Date
    $SyncLogList = Get-AzSqlSyncGroupLog  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                           -ServerName $ServerName `
                                           -DatabaseName $DatabaseName `
                                           -SyncGroupName $SyncGroupName `
                                           -StartTime $SyncLogStartTime.ToUniversalTime() `
                                           -EndTime $SyncLogEndTime.ToUniversalTime()
    if ($SynclogList.Length -gt 0)
    {
        foreach ($SyncLog in $SyncLogList)
        {
            if ($SyncLog.Details.Contains("Sync completed successfully"))
            {
                Write-Host $SyncLog.TimeStamp : $SyncLog.Details
                $IsSucceeded = $true
            }
        }
    }
}

if ($IsSucceeded)
{
    # Enable scheduled sync
    Write-Host "Enable the scheduled sync with 300 seconds interval"
    Update-AzSqlSyncGroup  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                -ServerName $ServerName `
                                -DatabaseName $DatabaseName `
                                -Name $SyncGroupName `
                                -IntervalInSeconds $IntervalInSeconds
}
else
{
    # Output all log if sync doesn't succeed in 300 seconds
    $SyncLogEndTime = Get-Date
    $SyncLogList = Get-AzSqlSyncGroupLog  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                           -ServerName $ServerName `
                                           -DatabaseName $DatabaseName `
                                           -SyncGroupName $SyncGroupName `
                                           -StartTime $SyncLogStartTime.ToUniversalTime() `
                                           -EndTime $SyncLogEndTime.ToUniversalTime()
    if ($SynclogList.Length -gt 0)
    {
        foreach ($SyncLog in $SyncLogList)
        {
            Write-Host $SyncLog.TimeStamp : $SyncLog.Details
        }
    }
}

# Clean up deployment 
# Remove-AzResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname
# Remove-AzResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $SyncDatabaseResourceGroupName
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can we see some documentation about where you found this or any other options?

Answer (score 0):

The azure rest api is a good option for syncing without having to rely on the auto sync. The POST api call has the form:

POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{serverName}/databases/{databaseName}/syncGroups/{syncGroupName}/triggerSync?api-version=2015-05-01-preview

Here's a link to the API doc:

[Azure rest api - Sync Groups - Trigger Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/syncgroups/triggersync)